# Langevin equation: Why is the autocorrelation of the noise term infinite?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, physics, correlation

In [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation) about Langevin equations they say that

> The force $\eta(t)$ has a Gaussian probability distribution with correlation function
> $$\langle \eta(t) \eta(t')\rangle = 2\lambda k_B T \delta(t-t').$$

My question is, where does this formula come from? My understanding is that the [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) is given by
$$\begin{aligned}
R_{\eta\eta}(t,t')&=E[\eta(t)\eta(t')] \\
&=\begin{cases}
\sigma^2_\eta, & t = t', \\
0, & t\ne t',
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}$$
where $\sigma_\eta^2$ is the variance of $\eta(t)$. Why is the formula above for the Langevin equation infinite at $t=t'$? Could you show me where that equation comes from and how $2\lambda k_B T$ relates to the variance of $\eta(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noise term, $\eta$, is a Gaussian white noise. That is, it is a stationary mean-zero Gaussian process with flat spectral density $S_{\eta}\equiv p$ ($p$ is the "power level" of $\eta$). The autocorrelation function of $\eta$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $S_{\eta}$, i.e.
$$
R_{\eta}(s)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(S_{\eta})=p\delta(s),
$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function. Specifically, the variance of $\eta(t)$ is infinite because otherwise the power spectrum would be a null function.

Comment: Are you sure the variance of $\eta(t)$ is infinite? Wouldn't that mean that on average the force at any point in time is infinite?